# Rake aborted when running "rake install" for Octopress?

Tags: ruby, git, github, octopress

I want to build Octopress on my Windows 8.1 system.

I installed Ruby 2.0.0, and DevKit in `C:\devKit`, then ran `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`.

They run successfully but when I run `rake install`, I always get an error message like:

```
rake aborted! cannot load such file -- 
     C:/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/octopress/Rakefile
```

I think the problem is that my username is Chinese, but could there be another problem?

I've tried `bundle update` or `bundle exec rake install` but it didn't work.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: If you think it my be your username, copy the whole `octopress` directory to `c:/` and try again.  I wouldn't be surprised if that worked.

Comment: @NickVeys Thanks a lot, you saved my time! .. I think I should change my username to english.

Comment: On a Windows machine especially! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clean up this question and to supply the right answer.

> I think the problem is that my username is **Chinese**, but could there be another problem?
>   The problem is that that current user has **non English** characters as the windows username.

This cause error and rake cant load the desired file.
Changing teh name or moving the the Octopress to a different folder fixed the problem.