# rake install command is not working (gem 'octopress', '~> 3.0.7')

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I am using windows8.1 . I saw some similar post at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865596/rake-aborted-when-running-rake-install-for-octopress) but I didn't get any solution.

```
C:\Sites\occtopress>bundle exec rake install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'install'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

here is my Rakefile:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

please help

Comment: can you post the contents of your Rakefile please?

Comment: @floum i added rakefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have not created any tasks file in lib/tasks, you won't have any task named install.

```
rake -T
```

will list all of your available tasks (look for a line starting with "rake install").

btw, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: brother i want to install and use gem "octopress" in my rails app but I couldn't . Thats why I post this question.

Comment: add `gem 'octopress', '~> 3.0.7'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

Comment: I did that , then its want "rake install" .

Comment: looking at the [readme](https://github.com/octopress/octopress) for octopress doesn't make it obvious you can run `rake install`. Have you tried `octopress init` ?